# It can't be held - what is this thing?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> It can't be held
>   but things appear
>   to have this thing
>   that some can hear.
>
> A butterfly is more inclined
>   discerning what you cannot find.
>   Wonder, war have often sprung,
>   songs and flags in tribute rung.

**What am I?**

Comment: I assume the question is "what is the object being described?" so I added the [riddle] tag.

Comment: @randal'thor what else should the question be? How many words does this riddle have? I think it doesn't always have to be stated so obviously.

Comment: Could be a butterfly's fart

Comment: @Avigrail Well, exactly - I assumed that's what the question was, so I added the [tag:riddle] tag. (Someone else, not me, later edited in the explicit "What am I?" line.)

Comment: @randal'thor That seems to be what we have been doing lately for riddles. So...

Comment: From a stylistic point of view this is one of the best riddles I've seen here lately. The flow and rhyming is as it should be. Now only the solution has to be gud and I'll be happy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer:

> Color/Colour

It can't be held

> I tried it...It can't be held

but things appear
to have this thing

> Almost Everything has a color

that some can hear.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia#Chromesthesia

A butterfly is more inclined
discerning what you cannot find.

> Butterflies can see in a larger spectrum than people:  http://www.butterflyzone.org/butterfly-articles/butterfly-uv-vision.shtml

Wonder, war have often sprung,

> I got nothing here

songs and flags in tribute rung.

> Flags have different colors.
>  And there are songs about colors
>  One color song:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQASh8bbkUY :D
>  More famous ones: http://rateyourmusic.com/list/gibboanx/the_50_greatest_songs_with_colours_in_their_titles/
>  and my favorite one from the list above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dY8_vZXo8oY Johnny Cash rules.

Side note:

> I'm color blind...stop it with these riddles.

Comment: Yes! As far as "Wonder, war have often sprung," the wonder part is a reference to things like rainbows and other wonderful colorful things. And the war is a reference to skin color, e.g. the US Civil War. So happy you answered this!

Answer (score 0):

I admit this is a try:

> Solution: A consequence?

but this words give me something to think

> It can be held could mean that is a property o something abstractand, after all, all choices have consequences. In fact the next line remembered me the **butterfly effect** from Ray Bradbury's novel *A sound of thunder* in wich a simple kill of a butterfly in the past have a lot of consequences.War and wonder are consequences in this novel (the second in the reader!). It is true that a thunder can be heard too, but it seem an even worst solution...

Comment: good try! but how is a butterfly more discerning of consequences?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might be

> Freedom

It can't be held
but things appear
to have this thing
that some can hear.

> Freedom is not tangible, but there are things that appear to have freedom (sometimes it's not real freedom). The last line could refer to 'hearing freedom ring' as was used during the abolitionist movement and later.

A butterfly is more inclined
discerning what you cannot find.
Wonder, war have often sprung,
songs and flags in tribute rung.

> Butterflies are often typified as 'free' and almost 'carefree'. The whole connection with wars and flags and tributes should be self-evident

Comment: good try, but can you really hear freedom?

Comment: No, but I thought the common phrase might be the link.

Comment: Ah yes, good guess.

Answer (score 0):

is it?

> wind

it can't be held

> you cannot held or touch wind

but things appear

> wind (and especially tornados) can bring things to you

to have this thing

??

that some can hear

> the sound of wind can be very heard to hear. also deaf people cannot hear the wind.

a butterfly is more inclined
discerning what you cannot find.

> a butterfly can feel and use the wind, even when you cannot see that there is wind. (too small a breeze to feel)

wonder, war have often sprung.

> wind also can be created by hot and cold air colliding / warring with each other.

songs and flags in tribute rung.

> songs are carried by the wind and flags are waving.

Comment: There is also the 'butterfly effect'.

Comment: Sorry, that's not it. Bit of a stretch to say that war and wonder have sprung from wind.